# Boot messages over ethernet

Tags: boot, networking, grub2, ethernet

I am trying to know the boot progress of a headless(no display) server.

[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SerialConsoleHowto) tutorial teaches how to receive the boot messages over a serial cable.

Is it possible to configure ubuntu to send boot messages over LAN?

I found [this](https://www.suse.com/communities/blog/netconsole-howto-send-kernel-boot-messages-over-ethernet/) article which shows how to do it on SuSE.

Need help in doing it on Ubuntu.

Comment: [Where do you send the kernel console on an embedded system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151687/where-do-you-send-the-kernel-console-on-an-embedded-system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done with the help of netconsole.
[Found it here.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Netconsole)